# Azure AD App registration user roles not reflecting

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have added an app registration with custom user roles through the manifest

I have successfully protected an API endpoint by way of the [authorize] atribute and roles.

I have now changed the names of the roles in AD but when I try to access the API endpoint I can see in the access token that the roles have not changed.

How long does it take for roles to change for a user? Do I need to do something else other than just change the names of the roles? Force a cache refresh somewhere? What am I missing?

I am using a private browser window to eliminate any stale cookie noise

Comment: if you query azure ad through graph API, will it display the right role name?

Comment: I used graph to query earlier and I saw all manner of weird things.  I mean weird between the application that was written to use the security and how groups/roles are set up in Graph.  I am in the process of writing a vanilla application to prove that all is set up correctly in Azure and that the main application is screwy.

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoCustodio and anyone else that took an interest, but I think I will close this for now as I just deleted the service prinicpal for the screwy application and waited.  Things "seem" to be behaving now, but I'm still not convinced but also dont have enough information to give anyone.

Comment: Sorry - I dont get notifications for some reason - all is working correctly now.  I will put it down to tiredness and not looking and changing where I should have.  Works correctly everytime now.

Comment: Facing the same issue, unable to resolve this currently. Strange behavior in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see in the access token that the roles have not changed.

Shouldn't the user role be reflected in Id token?

The decoded Id token.

[image]

> How long does it take for roles to change for a user? Do I need to do
>   something else other than just change the names of the roles?

We should change the value of the role, not the displayName. And it will take effect immediately.

```
"allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
            "displayName": "SurveyCreator2",
            "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "SurveyCreatorValue3"
        }
```

I changed the role value from `SurveyCreatorValue3` to `SurveyCreatorValue4`. We can see the update in the Id token.

[image]